# Using spark-py image in a bitbucket pipeline to perform pytest tests

Tags: pyspark, pytest, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use a spark-py image to run pytest tests in a bitbucket pipeline. Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
image: apache/spark-py:v3.3.2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: PyTest with PySpark
        script:
          - pip install --upgrade pip
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pytest -v tests/* --junitxml=test-results/report.xml
```

The most common problem I get is that no test report is found:

> Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results,
> failsafe-reports, test-reports, TestResults, surefire-reports] down to
> a depth of 4 Finished scanning for test reports. Found 0 test report
> files. Merged test suites, total number tests is 0, with 0 failures
> and 0 errors.

And I can't see any output from pytest, despite the -v option.

When running the same image in a simple Dockerfile, everything works fine:

```
FROM apache/spark-py:v3.3.2

USER root

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt /

# Install pytest and any additional dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["pytest"]
```

Even when trying to echo something and the pipeline passes, I get no output. What is wrong? How can I debug? How can I see anything really?

Thank you!

Googled a lot and asked chat gpt. I am expecting to see some kind of output, either from the tests with -v option or anything at all really

Comment: Have you tried to locate the output file yourself with ls, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and the root cause is the default user in the apache/spark-py image not having the rights to write its output to /tmp, where Bitbucket looks for log output etc..

I resolved the logging by changing the pipeline config for the image as follows, to run as uid 0:

```yaml
image: 
  name: apache/spark-py:v3.4.0
  run-as-user: 0  # The default user in the image does not have write rights to /tmp for logging to Bitbucket
```

I found this solution per the Atlassian knowledgebase here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/pipelines-build-completed-without-any-build-logs-1224641345.html